# Linear layout with five textviews and five edittextboxes

Tags: android, android-layout

here I have a problem with layout, I have taken a linear layout inside the relative layout and I want to have five text view's  and to their right  I want to add  five edit text boxes ,  I did the same but the layout is showing only 3 each,I mean three text-views and three edit-text boxes only, I couldn't able to solve , some one please help with the code

please help,  Thanks...!

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_one" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Name:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:maxLines="1"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_two" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_one">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_two">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dip"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_four" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_below="@+id/ll_three">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name:"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText04"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dip"
    android:password="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_three" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="New user"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @soorya  I posted it, is it ok

Comment: Post your code here so that we can see and find problem

Comment: @Dharmendra  Hi, I posted the total xml  code,plz view it once

Comment: I only see 1 line of code not the whole layout. By the way you're probably better off looking at TableLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the layout xml you posted and it looks as expected to me.

[image]

Of course, your layout xml has four rows of text views and edit views - not five rows.  Therefore, the screenshot has only four such rows.

Is this not what you're getting?

--

**Update**

To add a fifth row with another text view and edit text, you could just add the following to your original layout xml, just after the ll_four LinearLayout.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_five"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_four">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name:" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText05"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Then your original post is rather confusing.

Comment: @Raghav I don't know what your question is.  If I now understand you correctly, you've got four rows of text views and edit texts showing.  If you want a fifth, I'd guess you know how to make it appear, since you got the first four just fine.  In case you are just stuck adding the fifth, see the update I made to this answer to add some more xml.  At any rate, it may be beneficial to your getting help here, were you to clarify your question.

Comment: anthem  thanks a lot man, I used table layout to solve the prblm its working now but previously I stuck  with the layout , even I don't know why that's happened becoz I'm new to android. Any have thank u once again

Answer (score 0):

Hi Raghav can you post the layout code so that we can analyse it. What i think is that you can better embed your linear layout inside a ScrollView and for the sample refer this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example)

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: @Dinash  Hi, I posted the code ,could you view it? and let me know the problem with the code

Comment: @Dinash  I posted total code  but its not showing, what to do

Comment: @Raghav go through this [link to know about table layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) and wrap that table layout with a scrollview layout

Comment: hi raghav if u r still searching for the solution just try this piece of code '<ScrollView < android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  > <TableLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   > <TableRow> <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Name:"/> <EditText   android:layout_width="180px" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> </TableRow>  </TableLayout>   </ScrollView>' Fit this inside ur relative layout